# Assumptions for Factorial Analysis for Mixed Data

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

Are there assumptions that must be met to perform a Factorial Analysis for Mixed Data (FAMD)? Would Bartlett's sphericity test and KMO also be used, as in PCA? Or is it not necessary, as in MCA?

Comment: You should look at the _residuals_ from the model to see if they are approximately normal. Also look to see if residuals have approximately equal variances for various levels of the factor(s). // Not possible to be more specific answering this very general question.

Comment: For example, It's necessary to check if my data is adequate to implement a PCA, using Bartlett's sphericity test, and the measure of sampling adequacy, KMO index (well, and significant outliers and linear relationship) What I want to know is if for the FAMD there are tests or assumptions that my data must met before performing this method. Or it works like Multiple Correspondence Analysis, without any special assumption. My question is because FAMD is a mix of PCA and MCA, and because I cannot find a literature that specifically talks about this topic.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure of best answ to your Comment (from me or someone else), please edit your question to spell out acronyms KMO, PCA, MCA, FAMD, just to make sure we're all exactly on the same page.

Comment: @BruceET FAMD is Factorial Analysis for Mixed Data, a mix of Principal Component Analysis (PCA) and Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA). KMO is the Kayser-Meyer-Olkin Test for sample adequacy. [This](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/115-famd-factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-in-r-essentials/) is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.